# Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

When we submit our contact us form in SharePoint publishing site, on click event we getting below error. We use CEWP and REST API.

> {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"ar-SA\",\"value\":\"The
>   property 'Full_Name' does not exist on type
>   'SP.Data.Email_x0020_ConfirmationListItem

Below is the code, where i'm wrong?

```
enter <script type="text/javascript">
    var context;
    var web;
    var Url;
    var listItemEntity;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', FunctionReady);
        ItemSubmit();
    });


    <!-- function ItemSubmit() { -->
        <!-- $("#btnSubmit").click(function () { -->
            <!-- //reading text box values -->
            <!-- var titleValue = $("#name").val(); -->
            <!-- var columnValue = $("#email").val(); -->
            <!-- var titleValue = $("#name").val(); -->
            <!-- var titleValue = $("#name").val(); -->
            <!-- AddItemToList(listItemEntity, titleValue, columnValue); -->
        <!-- }); -->
    <!-- } -->
    function ItemSubmit() {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            //reading text box values
            var Fullname = $("#_name").val();
            var Email = $("#_email").val();
            var Telephone = $("#_Telephone_no").val();
            var Message = $("#_message").val();                         
            AddItemToList(listItemEntity, Fullname, Email,Telephone,Message);
        });
    }




    function FunctionReady() {
        context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = context.get_web();
        context.load(web);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFailure);
    }

    function onRequestSuccess() {
        Url = web.get_url();
        GetListItemEntity(Url);
    }
    function onRequestFailure(sender, args) {
        alert("Error Occured:" + args.get_message());
    }

    function GetListItemEntity(webUrl) {
        var queryUrl = webUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Email Confirmation')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName";
        $.ajax({
            url: queryUrl,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: onEntitySuccess,
            error: onEntityFailure
        });
    }


    function onEntitySuccess(data) {
        listItemEntity = data.d.ListItemEntityTypeFullName;
    }
    function onEntityFailure(err) {
        alert(err.statusText);
    }

    function AddItemToList(r, Fullname, Email,Telephone,Message) {
        try {

            var queryUrl = Url + "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Email Confirmation')/items";
            $.ajax({
                url: queryUrl,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                data: JSON.stringify(
                    {
                        '__metadata': {
                            'type': r
                        },
                        'Full_Name': Fullname,
                        'Email_Address': Email,
                        'Telephone_Number': Telephone,
                        'Full_Description': Message
                    }),
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                }, success: onQuerySucess,
                error: onQueryFailure
            });
        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert("Exception" + ex.message);
        }
    }

    function onQuerySucess() {
        alert('Item Added Successfully');
    }

    function onQueryFailure(error) {
        //alert("Failure:"+error.status+","+error.statusText);
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: *"The property 'Full_Name' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.Email_x0020_ConfirmationListItem"* So.. have you checked your Item for the proper Internal! name of the field?